# Formula for contour function estimates

Tags: r, formula, contour

I calculated a contour plot for some spatial data (x=lon,y=lat,z).

```
install.packages("akima")
library(akima)
lon <- runif(n=200,min=-180,max=180)
lat <- runif(n=200,min=-90,max=90)
z <- rnorm(n=200,mean=20,sd=1)
xo <- (-180:180)
yo <- (-90:90)
int <- interp(lon,lat,z,duplicate="mean")
contour(int,nlevels=50)
```

Now I'm looking for a way to obtain the mathematical function (a formula) behind those contours. In other words I'd like to get a function of z = f(lat,lon) to calculate estimates of z for any values of lat and lon.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the documentation. `interp` does linear interpolation. There is no function.

Comment: Any idea how to obtain a function? (Don't have to be based on my approach with interpolation.)